# jackson IntelliJ error when converting to unknown type in kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, intellij-idea, jackson, jackson-databind

In Kotlin, when trying to convert a request body into a Kotlin Object I get the following error in IntelliJ:

> None of the following function can be called with the arguments supplied

That's because it cannot infer the type of the object to convert to.

The application still builds and runs perfectly.

The IDE is right that it cannot infer the type of the resulting object but at runtime everything works as expected. The body is determined and then the deserialization is done properly and converted to the expected object type.

Even if this works the problem is only that I have the IDE error present in code.

```kotlin
val bodyMapper = payloadMapper(type)
val body = ObjectMapper().readValue(it.getPayload(), bodyMapper)
val body1 = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(it.getPayload(), bodyMapper)

private fun payloadMapper(type: String): Class<out Any> {
    return when (type) {
        "X" -> X::class.java
}
```

I use `jackson` and `jackson-kotlin`.

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21"
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.5.RELEASE"
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
```

[image]

The IDE error.

[image]

Comment: The usual cause for mismatches between the IDE warnings/errors and the compiler is a mismatch between the Kotlin version the IDE uses and that used to compile it (e.g. via Maven or Gradle).  So I'd double-check the version of the IDE's Kotlin plug-in and SDKs against that in any build script (`pom.xml` or `build.gradle`).

Comment: I added the configuration of the IDE and the build.

Comment: please show your full class content, I've tried OK
```
fun read() {
    val it = IT()
    val type = "X"
    val bodyMapper = payloadMapper(type)
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    val body = objectMapper.readValue(it.getPayload(),bodyMapper)
    val body1 = objectMapper.readValue(it.getPayload(),bodyMapper)
}
private fun payloadMapper(type: String): Class<out Any> {
    return when (type) {
        "X" -> X::class.java
        else -> Y::class.java
    }
}
class X {val value: Int = 0}
class Y {val value: Int = 0}
class IT {fun getPayload() = "{\"value\": 1}"}
```

Comment: @dungtavan it work, just like my code worked too... I updated the initial post with the IDE errors

Comment: Can you please file an issue at http://kotl.in/issue with a sample project to reproduce?